# Possible to use user:pass@host in JMeter HTTPSampler?

Tags: jmeter

I've been asked to test an app whose URLs were given to me as http://user:pass@host:port/path

I know this is HTTP Basic Authentication and the inclusion of the `user:pass` is discouraged by RFC 2396 (section 3.2.2).

I also expect that the application will receive the authorization in the header without a problem.

However, I decided to try and get JMeter to that the URLs in the format I was given anyway (just to try).

Two obstacles encountered.

First, although the username & password can be given to an HTTP Authorization Manager, it does not appear that there is a setting which allows this to be pushed onto the URL as an Authority at any point in the Manager or Sampler.

Second, the HTTP Sampler (including Request Defaults) does not take a userinfo / authority distinctly.

So, the only place to try seems to be in the HTTP Sample (or Defaults) domain field.

However, the domain is eventually passed to the `URL(protocol, domain, getPort(), pathAndQuery.toString())` constructor.

Adding `user:pass@host` to the domain will consequently result in a parsing exception later because the constructor interprets the `:` as an attempt to provide an IPv6 address and therefore encloses the host in square brackets (i.e. it literally converts the domain to `[user:pass@host]`).

So, bottom line, any there any methods I haven't considered which can use JMeter to accept a `user:pass@host` URL (aside from hacking the code or raising an issue with JMeter)?

As mentioned earlier, this is not recommended by RFC, so probably best to let this bit of archaic Internet badness die quietly. But curiosity compels.

Comment: For the equally curious, JMeter effectively makes this call (condensed from several locations): `new URL("http", "user:pass@example.org", 8888, "/stuff" ).toURI();`
which results in `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in user info at index 7: http://[user:pass@example.org]:8888/stuff`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, however you need to put the whole `http://user:pass@host:port/path` stuff into "Path" section of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

It will result in the request you're looking for (can be inspected using [View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) listener):

[image]

---

However if you need to access resources restricted by [basic HTTP authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) - the recommended way of bypassing it is using [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

Comment: Clever hack and I'd like to accept the solution, except that with HTTP Cookie Manager enabled, it results in `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host may not be blank` arising from the call originating in `CookieManager.getCookieHeaderForURL(CookieManager.java:356)`.  So, works in simple/trivial test plans, but can't use in a more robust test.